# C# : How to open configuration Pin Dialog?

Tags: c#, configuration, video, properties, dialog

I want to know what process to run with

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("", "");
```

that open this dialog. Thank you
[image]
This dialog come from Live broadcasting project of MS Expression encoder, Config pin Dialog of selected device.
[image]

Comment: From MS Expression Encoder 4 , Live Broadcasting Project, This Dialog show to configure the selected video device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dialog is not a separate executable that you can just run with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.  This is a configuration dialog for your capture device.  Your capture device is represented as DirectShow capture device.  This device is a COM object which implements the [ISpecifyPropertyPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695217%28VS.85%29.aspx), which is where the specific screen you are looking at comes from.   [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375480%28VS.85%29.aspx) is an MSDN article on how to display a DirectShow filter's property page.

Comment: Can it be executed without using Directshow? Is Expression encoder library can excute it?

Comment: I don't know of a way to get the dialog without creating a filter and querying its pages.  If you knew the GUIDS for the property pages you could just pass those into OleCreatePropertyFrame, but I don't know that you can get the GUIDS without querying the object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Expression Encoder SDK 4, then you can show this dialog and other configuration windows as follows:

```
 LiveDeviceSource _deviceSource;   
 ....
 if (_deviceSource.IsDialogSupported(ConfigurationDialog.VideoCapturePinDialog))
 {              
       _deviceSource.ShowConfigurationDialog(ConfigurationDialog.VideoCapturePinDialog, (new HandleRef(panelVideoPreview, panelVideoPreview.Handle)));
 }
```

You can see all the configuration dialogs supported by exploring Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Live.ConfigurationDialog type.

Comment: Is possible to display the VideoCapturePinDialog in modeless form not modal/dialog? If we want to know the change of setings directly, before pressing Ok button to apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is no program that you can run with that line to bring up that dialog.  (Unless you make one, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `LiveDeviceSource.ShowConfigurationDialog` function from the Expression Encoder SDK is usually a good choice. In my case, however, I had some capture sources that could not be properly instantiated by Expression Encoder if they are mis-configured. To configure them properly, I needed their configuration dialogs. So, I pulled together this solution using [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the IBaseFilter with the requested name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="deviceName">The friendly name of the device to retrieve</param>
/// <param name="deviceType">The type of device to retrieve</param>
/// <returns>Returns the filter with the given friendly name, or null if no such filter exists</returns>
public static IBaseFilter GetDeviceFilterByName(string deviceName, EncoderDeviceType deviceType)
{
    int hr = 0;
    IEnumMoniker classEnum = null;
    IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];

    // Create the system device enumerator
    ICreateDevEnum devEnum = (ICreateDevEnum)new CreateDevEnum();

    // Create an enumerator for the video or audio capture devices
    if (deviceType == EncoderDeviceType.Audio)
    {
        hr = devEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice, out classEnum, 0);
    } else
    {
        hr = devEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, out classEnum, 0);
    }

    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(devEnum);

    // no enumerators for video/audio input devices
    if (classEnum == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IBaseFilter foundFilter = null;
    // enumerate all input devices, looking for one with the desired friendly name
    while(classEnum.Next(moniker.Length, moniker, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
    {
        Guid iid = typeof(IPropertyBag).GUID;
        object props;
        moniker[0].BindToStorage(null, null, ref iid, out props);
        object currentName;
        (props as IPropertyBag).Read("FriendlyName", out currentName, null);

        if ((string)currentName == deviceName)
        {
            object filter;
            iid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
            moniker[0].BindToObject(null, null, ref iid, out filter);
            foundFilter = (IBaseFilter)filter;

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(moniker[0]);
            break;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(moniker[0]);
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(classEnum);
    return foundFilter;
}

/// <summary>
/// Opens the property pages for the filter with the given name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter">The filter for which we wish to retrieve and open the property pages</param>
public static void ShowDevicePropertyPages(IBaseFilter filter, IntPtr handle)
{
    // get the ISpecifyPropertyPages for the filter
    ISpecifyPropertyPages pProp = filter as ISpecifyPropertyPages;
    int hr = 0;
    if (pProp == null)
    {
        // if the filter doesn't implement ISpecifyPropertyPages, try displaying IAMVfwCompressDialogs instead
        IAMVfwCompressDialogs compressDialog = filter as IAMVfwCompressDialogs;
        if (compressDialog != null)
        {
            hr = compressDialog.ShowDialog(VfwCompressDialogs.Config, IntPtr.Zero);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
        }
        return;
    }

    // get the name of the filter from the FilterInfo struct
    FilterInfo filterInfo;
    hr = filter.QueryFilterInfo(out filterInfo);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    // get the propertypages from the property bag
    DsCAUUID caGUID;
    hr = pProp.GetPages(out caGUID);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    // create and display the OlePropertyFrame
    object[] oDevice = new[] {(object)filter};
    hr = OleCreatePropertyFrame(handle, 0, 0, filterInfo.achName, 1, oDevice,
                                caGUID.cElems, caGUID.ToGuidArray(), 0, 0, 0);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    // release COM objects
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(caGUID.pElems);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pProp);
    if (filterInfo.pGraph != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(filterInfo.pGraph);
    }
}

[DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int OleCreatePropertyFrame(IntPtr hwndOwner,
    int x,
    int y,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszCaption,
    int cObjects,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object[] lplpUnk,
    int cPages,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 6)] Guid[] lpPageClsID,
    int lcid,
    int dwReserved,
    int lpvReserved);
```

Usage:

```
var device = GetDeviceFilterByName(_settingsViewModel.VideoEncoderDevice.Name, EncoderDeviceType.Video);
ShowDevicePropertyPages(device, new HandleRef(ConfigurationDialogHost, 
                    ConfigurationDialogHost.Handle).Handle);
```